# Can SQL injection happen from inputed passwords if they are hashed?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement, password-protection

Is it recommended to bind the hash of a password to a prepared statement or should the hash be a normal part of the SQL statement?

```
if($createUserStmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'INSERT INTO users (name, pass) VALUES (?, ?)')
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($createUserStmt, 's', $_GET['username'], $passwordHash);
    //rest of prepared statment
}


if($createUserStmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'INSERT INTO users (name, pass) VALUES (?, '.$passwordHash.')')
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($createUserStmt, 's', $_GET['username']);
    //rest of prepared statment
}
```

For the password hashing function I'm using [this](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/README.md). Does the question come down to weather or not the output of the hashing function can produce code capable of SQL injection? Should the user input for the password be sanitized elsewhere? If yes, how?

@commenters please explain instead  of just saying "bad idea" or something that ammounts to that

Comment: Why do you want to eschew the working solution that is assured to be safe?

Comment: no no and no, the hash itself can NOT be used to exploit your db

Comment: No, but you should use parameters anyway for efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bcrypt hashes only consist of base64 characters (`.`, `/`, `0–9`, `A–Z`, `a–z`) and a leading `$2$` or `$2a$`, so it's safe from SQL injections. Although there is no reason to not pass it in as a parameter to the prepared statement as with everything else.

Comment: oh really, it doesn't slow it down if I bind more variables to a prepared statement instead of using string  concatenation?

Comment: No, prepared statements are faster because all values are parameters, the whole query (without values) can be saved and therefore the speed increase. If you prepare the statement with a value, it has to be prepared again when you change the password value.